# How to enable/disable menuitem (in contextmenu) for a selecteditem of treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I need to use a treeview control in WPF application
I create nested data (with type DataItem) and assign it to treeview control. 
Create a hierarchicaldatatemplate and assign it to treeview control
Add a contextmenu to treeview, 
Now I want to disable or enable the menu item by one property of SelectedItem (it should be DataItem, I think), "IsEnabled"

How to approach that?

```
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="dt" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_2" Text="{Binding Name}">
                </TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <TreeView x:Name="tree_3" Height="200"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dt}"
                  >
            <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                        Header="doA" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"  />
                    <MenuItem Header="doB" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="doC" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TreeView.ContextMenu>
        </TreeView>

class DataItem : DependencyObject //INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<DataItem> _items = new List<DataItem>();
    public List<DataItem> Items 
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataItem> allData = new List<DataItem>();

        DataItem i1 = new DataItem() { Name = "Test1", Category = 1, IsEnabled = false };
        DataItem i2 = new DataItem() { Name = "Test2", Category = 2, IsEnabled = false };
        DataItem i3 = new DataItem() { Name = "Test3", Category = 3, IsEnabled = true };

        DataItem t1 = new DataItem() { Name = "Template 1", Category = 1, IsEnabled = true  };
        DataItem t2 = new DataItem() { Name = "Template 2", Category = 1, IsEnabled = false };

        i1.Items.Add(t1);
        i1.Items.Add(t2);

        allData.Add(i1);
        allData.Add(i2);
        allData.Add(i3);
        tree_3.ItemsSource = allData;
    }
```

I resolved the problem by the following method.

1. create a context menu resource

   ```
   <ContextMenu x:Uid="ContextMenu_1" x:Key="TreeViewItemContextMenu"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}">
       <MenuItem x:Uid="MenuItem_1" 
             Header="Rename" 
             IsEnabled="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource renameMenuConverter}}"
             Click="RenameMenu_OnClick"
             />
   </ContextMenu>
   ```
2. create a style for the tree view item and using the context menu resource above

   ```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Uid="Style_1">
   <Setter x:Uid="Setter_32" Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource           TreeViewItemContextMenu}">
   </Setter>
   ...
   </Style>
   ```
3. implement a converter. According to the markup extension above, the parmeter passed in convert is the current selected item, so I can get the property of it and do the checking.

thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in WinForm TreeView with successful results.

When declaring the DataItems also include a tag property in them.

```
DataItem i1 = new DataItem() { Name = "Test1", 
                  Category = 1, IsEnabled = false, Tag = "Test1" };
```

On the EventListener for the TreeView, cast sender object or get the SelectedItem from the TreeView.

```
//It is only Algorithm:
if treeview1.selecedItem.Tag = "Test1" then
    //code for execution
end if
```

Similarly for the sender object,

```
//It is only Algorithm:
variable treeNode = cast ( sender to TreeView ).SelectedItem
if treeNode.Tag = "Test1" then
    //code for execution
end if
```

As for the "code for execution" you can enable or disable the MenuItems.

NOTE: You haven't declared x:Name attribute for the MenuItems in the ContextMenu Tag.
Please do that to access the MenuItems.

IsEnabled is the direct property for enabling or disabling the interactable items in WPF

I just gave the algorithm because, I'm more of a VB guy than C#. SO I don't want to mess up with the codes.

Have a great day :)

Comment: You can also add unique identifiers in the Tag property. You may ask "I can use the Name of the DataItem to access them?" But to do that you either declare them Globally as Friend or you use it in the Designer Code. Otherwise you cannot handle that object. You can also add a explicit Event Listener for the DataItems to do the job. As always a programmer has as many tactics as branches in a tree!